# Control popup dialog inner HTML in a proprietary library from Angular 2

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I am developing a component for the [WiX](http://www.wix.com) website builder using Angular 2. There is requirement that the WiX proprietary library [UI-Lib](http://wix.github.io/wix-ui-lib) be used.

To create a popup dialog in the library, I need to call the API

```
var popup = Wix.UI.create({ctrl: 'Popup', options: {}});
```

where one of the values in the `options` object (`content`) is the inner HTML of the popup as a string.

What is the best way to do this from Angular 2  so that the inner HTML retains all of the advantages of Angular, including binding and child components?

If I simply hard code a string as the inner HTML, I will need to use a library like jQuery to control the popup at a much lower level of abstraction than Angular 2 allows, unless there is some way to have Angular control this inner HTML.

Comment: In short, angular2 does not parse the content put into `[innerHTML]`. You may need dynamic component. You can check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39008455/1810391 .